# How can I extract the values ​from an object into an array while getting rid of multiple arrays in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object called copy selected Places.
At this time, I want to make the object in the form of an array.

So when I used Object.entries, the value I wanted did not come out. How do I fix my code?

this is my code

```
      const copyselectedPlaces = {
            A: true
            B : true
            C: true
            D :false
       }
```

i used Object.entries

```
     const arraypickplaces = Object.entries(copyselectedPlaces);
    arraypickplaces: [
        ['A', true]
        ['B', true]
        ['C', true]
        ['D', false]
        ]
```

expected answer

```
      arraypickplaces: [
        A: true,
        B : true
        C: true
        D :false
          ]
```

Comment: Your expected outlook is not a valid Array. What you are trying to achieve looks like the Map object which holds value and key pairs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: The "expected answer" is not possible in Javascript, each entry must be enclosed in something, for example as a string (`"A: true",`) or an object (`{A: true},`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanted to get an array of objects which you could achieve in this way:

```js
const copySelectedPlaces = {
  A: true,
  B: true,
  C: true,
  D: false,
};

function objectToArrayOfObjects (obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));
}

console.log(objectToArrayOfObjects(copySelectedPlaces));
```